# Polymorphism across C++ and Ruby using SWIG

Tags: c++, ruby, inheritance, polymorphism, swig

I use SWIG to wrap a Ruby script around a C++ library.  In Ruby, I can inherit from a C++ class, but I cannot pass the resulting pointer to a C++ function in a polymorphic way.

Here is a concrete example.  The SWIG interface file defines base class Animal with virtual function sound():

```
[animals.i]
%module(directors="1") animals
%{
#include "animals.h"
%}

// Apply the 'director' feature to a virtual function,
// so that we can override it in Ruby.
%feature("director") Animal::sound;
class Animal {
public:
    Animal();
    virtual ~Animal();
    virtual void sound();
};

class Dog : public Animal {
public:
    Dog();
    virtual ~Dog();
    virtual void sound();
};

// This function takes an Animal* and calls its virtual function sound().
void kick(Animal*, int);
```

Note that I use SWIG directors for cross-language polymorphism, but this does not seem to work.  The Ruby script looks like this:

```
[tst.rb]
require 'animals'
include Animals

dog= Dog.new   # Instantiate C++ class
kick(dog, 3)   # Kick the dog 3 times => It barks 3 times.
               # So far so good.

class Cat < Animal   # Inherit from a C++ class
   def initialize
      puts "Creating new cat"
   end

   def sound
      puts "Meow"
   end
end

cat= Cat.new   # Instantiate Ruby class

kick(cat, 9)   # This does not fly.
```

The final line in the script produces this error:

```
Expected argument 0 of type Animal *, but got Cat #<Cat:0xb7d621c8>
```

So somehow SWIG does not allow me to treat the Ruby object as a pointer-to-Animal.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got a solution to my problem from Tobias Grimm at the swig-user mailing list.
The first part of the problem is SWIG's misleading error message.
The message seems to suggest that I pass the wrong type of pointer to my C++
function, but this is not the case.  If you check the class of the exception
in Ruby, it's ObjectPreviouslyDeleted, meaning that the underlying C struct pointer
of my Cat class is NULL.  So the real problem is that the pointer is NULL,
not that it has the wrong type.

The pointer is NULL because I simply forgot to call "super" in Cat's initialize()
method.  This way, with the creation of Cat no underlying C struct gets allocated,
because the Animal constructor never gets called.
Forgetting to call 'super' is a very common Ruby-beginner's mistake, especially
for people like me who come from C++, who are used to automatic constructor chaining.

So all I had to do was add a call to 'super':

```
class Cat < Animal   # Inherit from a C++ class
   def initialize
      puts "Creating new cat"
      super()
   end
   def sound
      puts "Meow"
   end
end
```

This now works fine.  Thanks, Tobias.

Comment: Thanks man!
Really, if `super()` is not called from the overwritten `initialize()` method, then got error `ObjectPreviouslyDeleted` when pass Ruby to C++.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to define a [helper function](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Ruby.html#Ruby_nn16) that returns a pointer to your instance.
I have only used pointers with fopen, so I don't know if this will really work, or if there is something else I am missing.
Good luck!